# "configure: error: invalid variable name: `–prefix'" while runing configure

Tags: compiling, configure

I got the following error:

```
jay@ubuntu:~/Downloads/systemc-2.3.1/objdir
$ sudo ../configure –prefix=/usr/local/systemc-2.2
configure: error: invalid variable name: `–prefix'
```

Comment: Did you copy-paste the command from somewhere? if so try actually typing it instead - it should be `--prefix` (with two hyphens). Sometimes these things get mangled by HTML.

Comment: Also, there's usually no need to run `configure` with super-user privileges. The only point where you need that is `sudo make install`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: done - thank you for your comments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you copy-paste the command from somewhere? if so try actually typing it instead: it should be `--prefix` (with two hyphens). Sometimes these things get mangled by HTML, in this case yours looks like `e2 80 93, unicode EN DASH` instead of an ASCII `--`.

Also (thanks @DavidFoerster) you don't need to run the configure script using `sudo` when you are in your home directory tree, and in fact doing so complicates things (by leaving root-owned files there, which subsequent non-sudo build attempts can't overwrite). You should only use `sudo` for the final `make install` and **if** your install prefix is set to a system directory where you don't have write permission.